# py как узнать, или пользователь первый раз запускает бота телеграм

Tags: python

как узнать, запускал ли пользователь телеграм бота( Или сейчас первый запуск, или уже запуск был?)

Comment: Всмысле как просто прогу?

Comment: самый точный ответ можно получить у этого пользователя. если, конечно, не соврёт.

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду, когда пользователь вводить /start в боте телеграм, написал в заголовке

Answer (score 1):

Создай папку в профиле пользователя и смо три по её наличию

```
import os
firstrun = False
appname = 'suprbot'

if os.name == 'posix':
    path = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'), '.config', appname)
elif os.name == 'nt':
    path = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), appname)


if not os.path.exists(path):
    firstrun = True
    os.makedirs(path)

print(firstrun)
```

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду, когда пользователь вводить /start в боте телеграм, написал в заголовке

Comment: перепиши вопрос полностью)